# Ansible - how to run role in a loop for a given number of times

Tags: loops, ansible

Im using Ansible to deploy my app to aws. when i create the environment in aws i want to deploy x servers of type 'mq' (sometimes only 1, sometimes 3)
in my group_vars/all i have a key:

```
number_of_mqs: 3
```

Given that, I want my role to include a task for 3 times, how can i do that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could call a role within a task something like this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  tasks:
    - name: Call role 3 times
      with_sequence: count=3
      include_role:
        name: name_of_the_role
      vars:
        foo: "foo-{{ '%02d'|format(item|int) }}"
```

In this case, it will call the role 3 times passing the variable `foo` to it.